# Custom Loss Function for unsupervised learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, loss-function

I need to create my own loss (objective) function to minimize, as written in [this paper](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/151/5/054112/198621/Computing-committor-functions-for-the-study-of) (eq. 18).

From my understanding, I need to compute the module of the gradient with respect to the input and pass this "error" through backpropagation.

However, my objective function looks like:

```
def loss_function(points, outputs):
 a,b = minA, minB
 r, mul = 0.1, 1000
 N = len(points)
 grad_summed = 0.0

 for i,c in enumerate(points) :
   c = c.detach()
   c.requires_grad_()

  #outputs[i] is the output of the network from the forward pass
  XA = (1/2 -1/2 * torch.tanh(mul*(((c[0] - a[0])**2 + (c[1] - a[1])**2) - (r + 
       0.02)**2)))
  XB = (1/2 -1/2 * torch.tanh(mul*(((c[0] - b[0])**2 + (c[1]- b[1])**2) - (r + 
        0.02)**2)))
  q = (1-XA)*((1-XB)*outputs[i] + (XB))
  print("q", q)
  q.backward(retain_graph=True)
  gradient = ((c.grad)**2).sum()
  grad_summed += gradient

grad_avg = grad_summed/N
return grad_avg
```

(I'm also providing the code in this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FW5a7rXILcw49VHloIf-CXv65u1ahd6y?usp=sharing))
The issue is that, since I am already computing the gradient in the loss function, the following error arises when calling loss.backward() :

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

This makes sense, since .grad returns a scalar and there's no memory of the previous computations. Indeed, `retain_graph=True` only retains the computational graph.

How  should I write this objective function and how can I perform the minimization in this "unconventional" setting?